# Magic quotes isn't off (Strange problam!)

Tags: php

I tried to turn off magic quotes in these places:
`/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`
I'm sure all of them is "Off".

but it's still ON in phpinfo()! Here is my phpinfo()

```
magic_quotes_gpc    On  On
magic_quotes_runtime    Off Off
magic_quotes_sybase Off Off
```

The only way it works is add `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off` to .htaccess.

Now I want to disable it in `php.ini`. How can???

**Edit:**

phpinfo() shows:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/apache2
Loaded Configuration File   /php.ini
```

so I opened /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini. These are the magic-quotes-related things:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off

; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
; http://php.net/magic-quotes-runtime
magic_quotes_runtime = Off

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
; http://php.net/magic-quotes-sybase
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

Comment: Have you restarted your server after doing these changes?

Comment: Yes after one change, I restart Apache2

Comment: Is it your local server or main live server like `godaddy`?

Comment: You should restart PHP as well... `sudo service php5-fpm restart`

Comment: Perhaps you're editing the wrong ini file? Look at the output of phpinfo and note down the file mentioned in "Loaded Configuration File".

Comment: @Salman A: Loaded Configuration File /php.ini      Is it right?

Comment: @max: I use /etc/init.d/apache2 restart. I use Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: `/php.ini` is odd. Still, try changing the settings in that file.

Comment: That is really odd. Could you - just to test (!!!) - make a symlink using `sudo ln -s /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /php.ini` and restart your server? (Remove the symlink after you've tested this!)

Comment: If you're on ubuntu 12.04, is there a dir / symlink called `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d`, and is it mentioned inside your phpinfo()'s output?

Comment: I just checked on my ubuntu box, and `/php.ini` is not the path that is listed in my .ini output. Are you running PHP in some kind of a chrooted environment? Or did you by chance compile your own PHP?

Comment: see my edit, it's actually /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini :D

Comment: Hmm. Weird. Just to be sure, could you run `grep -r magic_qoutes /etc/php5` and `grep -r magic_quotes /etc/apache2` and post the output here?

Answer (score 1):

php.ini's settings should be respected by PHP, so if the default value is also reported to be 'On', PHP probably failed to read the value from your .ini file.

Here's what to do:

1. Share with us the line of config that you added to your php.ini to disable it. It may be the case that you just made a typo. It should look something like this.

   ```
   magic_quotes_gpc = Off
   magic_quotes_runtime = Off
   magic_quotes_sybase = Off
   ```
2. Make sure that there aren't multiple occurrences of magic_quotes_gpc in your ini file(s)!
3. Make sure you're editing the correct .ini file(s)! Open your `phpinfo()`'s output, and look at the "Configuration File (php.ini) Path" and "Additional .ini files parsed". Check these files for an entry of `magic_quotes_gpc`.

   - Note that it may differ whether you run phpinfo() on the CLI or using your web server!
4. Although this is very unlikely to be the issue considering what you say `phpinfo()` reported, ensure that you are not overriding stuff in your web server's configuration.

Comment: Question info added. There is only one occurrence of magic_quotes_gpc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function in your php file, it will works

```
set_magic_quotes_runtime(false);
```

**Note**

*This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.*

Comment: The OP is referring to the setting of `magic_quotes_gpc`, not `magic_quotes_runtime`. There is no corresponding PHP function to set `magic_quotes_gpc` at _runtime_ (which can only be set in php.ini, .htaccess, server config, etc).